# How to expose an NSMutableArray as an NSArray as a return type from a method

Tags: ios

I have a model class which contains an NSMutable array of objects. The controller classes need to have access to this array, however that access should be read only.

How should this be implemented? Should the model expose the array as a (readonly) NSMutable array and use consts, or expose it as an NSArray? If the latter how can the NSArray be created efficiently from the NSMutableArray i.e. how should the NSArray contain a reference to the NSMutableArray/its contents rather than have duplicate copies? (the NSMutableArray is guaranteed to persist in memory while the controllers access it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just return your `NSMutableArray` directly:

```
- (NSArray *)method
{
    return myMutableArray;
}
```

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so the controllers will be able to perform all of the `NSArray` operations on it already.  If you're really concerned that somebody might be trying to pull tricks on you, you could use:

```
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutableArray];
```

to return an immutable copy.

Comment: +1 - just bear in mind that using dot accessor syntax would kill performance, so myself I'd prefer first variant ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no read only NSMutableArray. If you are thinking that defining a property as read only makes the returned object immutable, this is not the case.

Expose a read-only property of type NSArray, and in the accessor return a new array as follows:

```
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
```

Note that the objects within the array, if mutable, will still be changeable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue passing your mutable array, but want to ensure that the other method does not overwrite your existing array, you could always pass a copy

```
return [myMutableArray copy];
```

This way, you are returning a type NSArray (since NSMutableArray is a subclass) and ensure that myMutableArray itself is not getting tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, so there is nothing to be done to expose NSMutableArray as an NSArray except to (probably implicitly) cast it. Note that it's still the same object, so if someone wants to be clever, they can downcast it or even just try to call NSMutableArray methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

While this might be overkill, you could create your own custom class that has a @private ivar of an array, and then you could create readonly properties/methods to access data only.

i.e (implementation snippet):

```
@interface CustomArray : NSObject
{
    @private
    NSArray *array;
}

@end

- (id)initWithNSArray:(NSMutableArray *)array;

- (id)getObjectAtIndex:(int)index;

@implementation

// implement methods here

@end
```